# TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server for VS 2010, VS 2012 is connected to same server from same machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, tfs

I have VS2012 and VS2010 on the same machine. VS2012 is connected to  Team Foundation Server (now VSOL/Visual Studio Online) but, VS2010 gives below error when trying to add  Team Foundation Server (now Visual Studio Online) to the list.

**TF31002:** Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server
Possible reasons for failure include:

- -The name, port number or protocol for TFS is incorrect.
- -The team foundation server is offline.
- -Password has expired or is incorrect.

For further information, contact  Team Foundation Server administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe VS2010 requires VS2010 Service Pack 1 and a compatibility patch (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) to connect to TFS 2012.  Do you have those?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded both of them.

Comment: As I recall, the interface for adding the server is a bit different between VS2010/VS2012 also.  Did you specify the appropriate virtual directory, port, and protocol?

Comment: yes I did. BTW I get KB26662296 does not apply or is blocked by another condition on your computer.

Comment: I've only seen that before when VS2010 SP1 hasn't already been installed.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on different interface between vs2010/vs2012?

Comment: I am sure its there. Team was added to menu after downloading SP1. Will try downloading it again though. Had some memory problems while downloading SP1.

Comment: It's been awhile, to be honest.  I *thought* one of them had a textbox for specifying the port, while you had to bake the port in to the server URL in the other version.  For example, http://tfsserver:8080/tfs.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. In your suggestion, I downloaded sp1 again and this time vs2010 connects to tfs.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to run the TFSConfig command with the ChangeServerID parameter as follows:

1)     Open elevated command prompt and change current directory to c:\Program Files\Microsoft TeamFoundation Server 12.0\Tools

2)     Execute “TfsServiceControl.exe quiesce”

3)     Execute tfsconfig changeserverid  /sqlinstance: /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration /projectcollectionsonly .
        Make sure to pass projectcollectionsonly parameter.

4)     Execute “TfsServiceControl.exe unquiesce”

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have done a full scan(Anti -Virus) to your laptop -> TFS work space don't connect to the TFS server and gives TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server Error.

Reason: Full Anti-Virus scan to a machine un-mounts and mounts the network drives, which leads to breaks the mapping of local drive to the TFS server path.

Solution: 
1.  Clear the cookies in following path
c:\Users\jekumar\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
2.  If it still doesn’t help 
a.  Disconnect from Team Foundation server ( VS IDE -> Team-> Disconnect from Team Foundation Server)
b.  Rename the locally mapped folders 
c.  Now connect to Team Foundation server ( VS IDE -> Team-> Connect to Team Foundation Server)

Comment: This can be looked into when you have recently full scanned your machine with Anti Virus