# TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server VS2010- VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, tfs

`I know this question has been asked many times over here.`

**But nothing worked for me and I'm still unable to resolve my issue.**

Problem is

[image]

It was working yesterday but then I restarted my laptop and I haven’t changed anything but the issue is here. I'm facing this issue on both `VS2010` and `VS2013`.

I've tried many solutions like

1) `Installing SP1` and `compatibility Patch` as
[Suggested here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20231249/2660342)

2) `Clearing local cache` of **Team Foundation Server**

3) `Removing all credentials` from **Control Panel** and then re-adding them

4) `Uninstalling` any **proxy server** that I'd installed

I can even connect to **Team Foundation Server** through Team System Web Access with same URL *(**http://tfsserver:8080/**)* but its not working for any **Visual Studio**.

Is there any other solution that I'm missing?? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the network connected?
Basic stuff like ping <tfsserver> and telnet <tfsserver> 8080 can tell if you can reach the machine.

Comment: yes i can ping <tfsserver>

Comment: Can you load the web portal in a browser?

Comment: yes I can load it in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I don't know whether it actually is the solution or not` But the only change that I've made yesterday was to **Clear my browser's history** and the problem just went away.

After clearing browser's history, when I built my solution, **TFS** login window prompted, I gave my userName/ Password and here it is connected to Team Foundation Server.

I'm posting it over here just because if someone else is facing the same issue, make sure that you are `clearing your browsers' history and deleting all the cache.` It may also resolve your issue like mine.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can connect to TFS through web portal, so there is nothing wrong with TFS server.
To narrow down your issue, you can try below methods:

- Disable your firewall.
- Run VS2010 and VS2013 in admin mode.
- Disable antivirus or add TFS in whitelist.
- Connect to TFS with another user account or another machine.
- Use Ip  address like
  *http://x.x.x.x (your server Ip):8080/tfs* instead of server address

If you still can't solve it, you can try some steps described in this MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244143.aspx Also go through [VS logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) looking for the connection attempt and rejection reason.

Comment: your MSDN article link is missed or there must be some issue in link address.

Answer (score 2):

Replace server address with server IP works for me.
e.g

```
http://tfsaddress:8080/tfs/collection
```

replaced with

```
http://(your server ip):8080/tfs/collection
```